Error handling with typeorm, sql in Nestjs
I'm writing a service in Nestjs which uses typeorm to communicate with a MySQL server. Say, I create a table, test_table with two columns col1 and col2, col1 having a UNIQUE constraint.
If try to insert a duplicate value I get an error which looks like:
{
  query: 'INSERT INTO `test_table`(`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (?, ?)',
  parameters: [ 'test-val-1', 'test-val-2' ],
  driverError: {
    code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
    errno: 1062,
    sqlState: '23000',
    sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry 'test-val-1' for key 'test_table.col1'",
    sql: "INSERT INTO `test_table`(`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('test-val-1', 'test-val-2')"
  },
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlState: '23000',
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry 'test-val-1' for key 'test_table.col1'",
  sql: "INSERT INTO `test_table`(`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('test-val-1', 'test-val-2')"
}

If I return sqlMessage it exposes the table name and column name, I don't get the name of the erroneous column explicitly.
Is there a way to extract information in a format such that I can have the column name which is causing the error and what error is it causing?
There are two solutions I can think of:

Checking for duplicate entry by hitting the db before trying to insert. It will increase latency because of additional database calls.

Or I can write a parser which extracts the relevant information from the message but it seems like going overboard because if the message changes for some reason, it breaks.



Did you try giving the SQL command directly in DB?

@Martin54 it gives me the same error which type orm wraps in the object. My problem is retrieving relevant information. I don't really understand what you suggested.

Parsing sqlMessage is really some kind of nonsense. Moreover, there may be a conflict with several records. Pre-check is also not the best option.
Just write an error handler for errno: 1062. You can use try catch. In the processor, look for problematic records. I think this is the optimal solution.

This is what I ended up doing, making separate error classes for the error I might run into. I'm just looking for an approach which can handle this in class (if possible).
